# Set query params in url angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, i have this url: `http://local.com/`. When i call the function in my `SearchController` i want to set `text=searchtext` and get an url like this:
`http://local.com/?text=searchtext`.

How can i do this? I have tried `$location.search('text', 'value');` but I got this url: `http://local.com/#/?text=searchtext`

```
$scope.searchTracks = function() {

    Search.search.get($scope.params, function(data) {
        /** Set params in query string */
        $location.path('/').search('text', $scope.text);       
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set html5mode in your module's config in order to get rid of the #/ in the URL.

[see the angularjs guide on using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Additionally you will may want to set `reloadOnSearch` to false in your route configuration if you don't want your controller/route to reload when you change the query parameter.

Example:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
      $routeProvider.when('/', {
           /*{other route options here}*/
           reloadOnSearch: false
      });
});
```

Comment: @iilexial Are you using `<a ng-href="/mypath">link text</a>` on your links? Specifically note the `ng-href` part. Angular won't be able to work with your routes on links with just a standard `href`. Also make sure you don't have `#/` in front of your links now that html5mode is enabled.